# How to get access to private s3 bucket using cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I have a cognito user pool which is connected to google as identity providers (so that I can log in with a gmail account). I also have a private bucket s3 with files ().  How can I use my lambda function, using the token returned by Cognito (AcessToken, IdToken) to get access to my s3 bucket which is not public?

I just want to use my cognito to access my private files on s3.

Something like the Cognito Authorizer for lambda functions just for s3 bucket.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) to achieve this.

Basically, after your user successfully authenticated by Cognito, your Lambda function will generate s3 pre-signed url for object requested and reply it back.

[Example from AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html)

Also take a look at this [AWS forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=688741)

Comment: But this will generate a link that will be valid for some time and anyone who gets the link will have access to the object.  I would like the resource to be directly protected by a cognito.

Comment: You can make this TTL very low, so it can be used only once and not shared with anyone. Otherwise, you'll have to proxy whole file body from s3 through your lambda (with Lambda 6mb size limit), or proxy using any other solution deployed on EC2

Comment: Signed URLs are not needed. Using the AWS SDK and your Cognito id_token, you can request for AWS credentials (temporary).

Answer (score 1):

The only way that i know to do this is give the role access to the cognito user

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html